# SQL: how to return nth value from json in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to SELECT and parse a javascript list in a postgres table column, it has no keys:

```
{coastal,transitional,contemporary,romantic,traditional,
industrial,modern,contemporary_eclectic,regency,mediterranean}
```

What SQL command get's the nth value?

I know you can get values by key like this:

```
SELECT {column_name}->>{key value}
FROM {table_name}
```

But I really want to just pull values by list-value order.  Is there some syntax that I cannot find?  Or do I need to transform this array into a different data type?

Answer (score 6):

The same actually works for arrays:

```
{column_name}->>N
```

where `N` is the integer position of an element.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: I don't know, I couldn't get that to work.  I just figured out the 'ish' though: it's typical syntax for JS, just doesn't start counting at 0:

e.g.: {column_name}[1] is the first value in the list

Comment: @TaylorNelson it definitely is 0-base indexed.

Comment: Right, I think I had a postgres array... dumb on my part, or rather, that was the real issue, I thought I had a json.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I asked the wrong question--I have a postgres array, not a JSON:

I was struggling because posgres starts counting arrays at position 1, not 0--doh!

```
{column_name}[1] //this is the first value in the array
```

Comment: So, you don't have a JSON but a porstgresql array?

Comment: Correct, your solution is great for my question, I asked the wrong question because I thought it was a JSON array, which we have abundantly in our schema.  Thanks!